# MSCRM 2016 Share privilage not working

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016, dynamics-crm-365

Can any one help that why user is not able to share his personal chart if he has the permission to share the chart at User level.

He is not system Admin but share permission is given clearly.

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Please elaborate on "not able to": doesn't see the button, sees the button but it's non functional, everything seems to work but other user doesn't see the chart ... ?

Comment: Does not see the the button :(

Comment: Does the user have a Share View permission?

Comment: You mean 'Share' permission to 'User Chart' ? and the answer is yes.
Still user is not seeing the 'Share' button.

Comment: No, I mean Share permission to Saved View. It is on Core Records tab in Security Role definition.

Comment: Yes, it is also given at user level.I do not know why issue is not occuring in lower environment but this issue is occuring in QA environment. I have compared the security roles with each and every circle :(

Comment: I was confused and not getting any reason behind this issue. Finally, I re-imported the solution from DEV to QA and now it worked in QA environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was confused and not getting any reason behind this issue as every required role and privilege was given. Finally, I re-imported the solution from DEV to QA and it worked in QA environment for me.

Thanks.